# An infinit recursive call in constructor

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript and I was looking for some code on GitHub. Then I found the definition of BSON in js_bson library (part of MongoDB Node.JS driver)

Isn't this constructor referencing itself without mutating the parameter, which would result in an infinite call and eventually a stack overflow ?

```
  constructor(inputId?: string | number | ObjectId | ObjectIdLike | Buffer | Uint8Array) {
    if (!(this instanceof ObjectId)) return new ObjectId(inputId);
```

For me, if the first call was passing a number, then calling `new ObjectId(inputId)` is always the same as calling the constructor with a number.

Or is there any type inference here in the definition of ObjectId type; Like returning a new ObjectID would recall itself with the type of ObjectID and not the number.

Comment: It only goes recursive if and only if `!(this instanceof ObjectId)`. When doing `new ObjectId(...)`, this condition should always be false. I.e., this just catches cases where the constructor was somehow invoked in a way that `this` is not an `instanceof ObjectId`, like `ObjectId(foo)` (without `new`).

Comment: hum interesting. I got ya